# How to change the RDP password to an Azure (Classic) VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp, change-password

In wanting to change the RDP password to my Azure VM (classic), the results from my research seemed far too complex to do this. So, I wanted to reach out to the StackOverflow community to verify if what I need to do is correct.

I have an Azure VM that was made prior to 2014. It has Windows Server 2012 as the operating system.

I first went to the Azure portal and to 'Reset Password' but was told that I needed to install Microsoft's VMagent on the VM.
[image]

- After installing the VMagent on the VM, I looked how to interact with the program. I read that I must have the Azure Powershell module installed on my VM.
- But before I can install the Azure Powershell, I need to have Powershell 5.0 installed on the VM (Currently it has 3.0).
- Before I can install Powershell 5.0, I need to update the .Net framework on the VM from 4.0 to 4.5 or higher.

That last part is what concerns me as this server is used for a number of services including hosting our websites, a couple of web services, and a reporting application.

So, has anyone else has had a similar situation and/or are there other ways to go about changing my RDP password to this VM?

Answer (score 0):

> I read that I must have the Azure Powershell module installed on my VM.

Maybe you read this article? [Install the VM Agent on an existing Azure VM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/04/07/install-the-vm-agent-on-an-existing-azure-vm/)

There is no requirement of installing Azure PowerShell module on your VM. You could install this module on your client. Actually, you just need to re-configure the VM to let the Azure platform know that the VM agent has been installed. But there is no GUI to make this change. That's reason why you need the Azure PowerShell Module. So, you could install this module on any client which has internet connection.

If you have Windows 10 client, PowerShell 5.0 is installed by default.

To install the PowerShell Module, please refer to this article: [Install and configure Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-3.8.0)